# How do I get lifetime of reference to owned object? (cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter)

Tags: rust

How do I get this to compile?

```
extern crate collections;
fn print_x_from_table(table: collections::BTreeMap<String, String>) {
    let x: &str = table
        .get(&String::from_str("x"))
        .map(|s: &String| &s[])  // ERROR!
        .unwrap_or("");
    println!("table contains x={}", x);
}
```

It gives this error:

```
src/rusttest.rs:5:22: 5:25 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'a in function call due to conflicting requirements
src/rusttest.rs:5       .map(|s: &String| &s[])
                                           ^~~
src/rusttest.rs:7:34: 7:35 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the expression at 7:33...
src/rusttest.rs:7   println!("table contains x={}", x);
                                                    ^
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:43: 2:76 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:78 note: in expansion of println!
src/rusttest.rs:7:2: 7:37 note: expansion site
src/rusttest.rs:7:34: 7:35 note: ...so type `&str` of expression is valid during the expression
src/rusttest.rs:7   println!("table contains x={}", x);
```

If `table` were a reference parameter, I know that I could add a type parameter `'a` to indicate how long `s` should live. But how do I do that when I own `table`?

```
extern crate collections;
fn print_x_from_ref_table<'a>(table: &'a collections::BTreeMap<String, String>) {
    let x: &'a str = table
        .get(&String::from_str("x"))
        .map(|s: &'a String| &s[])
        .unwrap_or("");
    println!("table contains x={}", x);
}
```

Comment: I think you've run into a compiler bug. I wrote a simpler example with `HashMap`, and was able to make it compile by removing the `: &String` annotation from the closure, which really shouldn't have made any difference.

Comment: I agree with @wingedsubmariner. This is probably worthy of an issue. I just tried it in playlen and removing the `: &String` in the closure works.

Comment: I also would like to mention that you don't need to construct a String from a literal for lookup. Just write `.get("x")`. `get` takes a `&Q` where `Q: BorrorFrom<K>`. And since `str: BorrowFrom<String>`, you can use a `&str` for lookup as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have filed bug [Can’t declare lifetime of closure that returns a reference #22340](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22340) in response.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by avoiding using closures and using match instead. I think this works because in `.map(|s| &s[])` the compiler gets confused and thinks the reference should live shorter than how long it actually lives for.

```
fn print_x_from_table(table: collections::BTreeMap<String, String>) {
    let x = match table.get("x") {
        Some(v) => &v[],
        None => ""
    };
    println!("table contains x={}", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a limitation of the closure syntax. Check out these alternatives:

```
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn inner<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a str { //'
    &s[]
}

fn inner2(s: &String) -> &str {
    &s[]
}

fn print_x_from_table(table: HashMap<String, String>) {
    let x = table
        .get("x")
        // .map(|s: &String| &s[])  // ERROR!
        // .map(inner) // OK
        // .map(inner2) // OK
        // .map(Deref::deref)  // OK
        .map(|s| &s[])  // OK
        .unwrap_or("");
    println!("table contains x={}", x);
}

fn main() {
}
```

In the second example, we use a function `inner` that has explicit named lifetimes that tie the input and the output together, letting the reference live beyond the closure. However, this is the exact case for lifetime elision, so `inner2` is the same concept, but shorter. We could also cut out the middleman and just use the `Deref::deref` method directly.

The last example doesn't specify any types, so the compiler automatically inserts them and ties the references together (this last part is a guess based on observation, not intrinsic knowledge). This is probably what you'd see most of the time; it's not super common to specify types when you don't need to.

One potential "solution" would be if we could specify lifetimes ourselves on the closure definition. A hypothetical syntax like

```
<'a>|foo: &'a String| -> &'a str { foo.bar() }
```

could do the trick, but I don't know of any way to make that work.